# How to append String to StringBuffer variable in JAVA

Tags: java, string, append, output, stringbuffer

My code is as  below. i need to add single quotes for each word in string with single quotes after appending DD to it.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ChkboxIds = "'a1b2c3','321cba','123abc'";
        String checkBoxId = null;
        String checkId = null;
        StringBuilder checkIDS = new StringBuilder("'");
        for(int i=0;i<=ChkboxIds.split(ChkboxIds, ',').length;i++){
            checkBoxId = "DD"+ChkboxIds.split(",")[i].replace("'","")+","+checkBoxId;
            checkId = checkBoxId.substring(0, checkBoxId.length() - 5);
            System.out.println("---PRINT---"+checkId);
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                checkIDS..append('\'').append(checkId.split(",")).append('\'').append(',');
                System.out.println("---PRINT123----"+checkIDS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using StringBuffer too. please point your answers here. The output i get is some junk data while i need the words with dd attached at the start.

Expected output:`'DDa1b2c3','DD321cba','DD123abc'`

Comment: `checkIDS..append('\'').append(checkId.split(",")).append('\'').append(',');`
beforethe first append there is 2 dots, delete one

Comment: what is "junk data" ?

Comment: You need to show the output you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the issue is not the dot, it was a mistake in the code regarding the dot.
and the junk data i am speaking about is : '[Ljava.lang.String;@d70c109',....

Comment: Thanks for you comment.. i have got the answer required and marked a green tick for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

- issue at `.append(checkId.split(","))` where you append an `String[]` so it's representation is it's hashcode
- don't need a second loop, each word need one loop round, no inner loop needed
- your split is wrong, you need `ChkboxIds.split(",")`, you don't need with the same string as delimiter

---

#### Fix

You can do much more simpler than that

- split on comma
- remove quotes, append `DD`, add quotes
- save at same place in array
- join array with comma

```
String chkboxIds = "'a1b2c3','321cba','123abc'";

String[] splitted = chkboxIds.split(",");
String checkBoxId;

for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    checkBoxId = "DD" + splitted[i].replace("'", "");
    splitted[i] = "'" + checkBoxId + "'";
}

String result = String.join(",", splitted);
System.out.println(result);
// 'DDa1b2c3','DD321cba','DD123abc'
```

Regex power

```
String chkboxIds = "'a1b2c3','321cba','123abc'";
String result = chkboxIds.replaceAll("'(\\w+)'", "'DD$1'");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer its very helpful and i got the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ids = Arrays.stream( ChkboxIds.split( "," ) ) // Separate the words
  .map( s -> s.replace( '\'', '' ) ) // Strip the single quotes
  .map( s -> "DD%s".formatted( s ) ) // Prepend with "DD"
  .collect( Collectors.joining( "','", "'", "'" ) );
System.out.println( ids );
```

Alternatively:

```
var ids = Arrays.stream( ChkboxIds.split( "," ) ) // Separate the words
  .map( s -> s.replaceFirst( "'", "'DD" ) ) // Replace the first single quote with the prefix
  .collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) );
System.out.println( ids );
```

Refer to the respective Javadoc for the details.

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, you can try the code below.

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ChkboxIds = "'a1b2c3','321cba','123abc'";
        //Replace all single quotes from the ChkboxIds, split them using comma delimiter, and store it to variable array
        String[] ChkboxIdsNew = ChkboxIds.replace("'","").split(","); 

        String checkIDS = ""; //String variable to be used to store the check ids

        //Loop through the ChkboxIdsNew array
        for (int i = 0; i < ChkboxIdsNew.length; i++) {
            //Only append comma if i is greater than zero
            if (i > 0) {
                checkIDS = checkIDS + ",";
            }
            //Concatenate the single quotes and prefix DD then append it to checkIDS
            checkIDS = checkIDS + "'DD" + ChkboxIdsNew[i] + "'";
        }


        System.out.println(checkIDS);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:
If the single words doesnt contain additional single quotes:

```
    String ChkboxIds = "'a1b2c3','321cba','123abc'";
    ChkboxIds = ChkboxIds.replaceAll(",'",",'DD").replaceAll("^'","'DD");
```

Using iteration :

```
    String arChkBoxIds[]= ChkboxIds.split(",");
    StringBuilder checkIDS1 = new StringBuilder("");
    for (String chkBoxId:arChkBoxIds){
       
       checkIDS1.append("'DD").append(chkBoxId.substring(1)).append(",");
    }
    checkIDS1.setLength(checkIDS1.length()-1);
    System.out.println(checkIDS1);
```